# Rounding float to nearest int with halfway toward zero

Tags: c++, c, rounding

Looking at the set of GNU provided rounding functions, I'm unable to find precisely what I'm looking for.

According to GNU [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html),
`rint()` and friends will round to an integer according to the current rounding mode, which defaults to *round to the nearest integer*.

This is mostly what I want, however it appears to be a halfway towards infinity model.
That is

```
llround ( 1.500000 ==  2), want  1
llround (-1.500000 == -2), want -1
llrint  ( 1.500000 ==  2), want  1
llrint  (-1.500000 == -2), want -1
```

The documentation for `round()` and friends states:
*These functions are similar to rint, but they round halfway cases away from zero instead of to the nearest integer (or other current rounding mode).*

I'm unable to determine any function that uses the default rounding mode, but with *halfway toward zero* semantics

Specifically, I would like

- Rounding towards nearest integer
- Halfway towards zero
- Both positive and negative values

Does any such exist?

In the meantime, I've taken the following approach.
I'm not terribly keen on this, but it gets the job done for my limited use case

```
(float_val > 0) ? llrint(float_val - __FLT_EPSILON__) : llrint(float_val + __FLT_EPSILON__)
```

Comment: `x - floor(x) == 0.5 ? (long long)(trunc(x)) : llrint(x)` could be used as an alternative

Comment: Can you use [`fesetround()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) + `rint()`?

Comment: @Shawn The rounding mode is already FE_TONEAREST by default which is the behaviour I want for all values except 0.5 (which seems to always be half toward inf)

Comment: Try producing a floating point result first, and then converting to `long long`.   For example,  `(long long)(float_val > 0? -std::floor(0.5 - float_val) : 0.5 - std::ceil(0.5 - float_val))`.    Incidentally, if you feel you really must use machine epsilon, use `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`, not a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: @Peter that looks good also. I was being lazy with the __FLT_EPSILON__ business, numeric limits def an improvement

Comment: Actually the `*rint()` functions take the half-integer values to the nearest _even_ integer. So sometimes towards zero, sometimes towards infinity. The `*round()` functions always round towards infinity.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (and since a couple of previous comments, including mine, have suggested possible solutions), why do you need this manner of rounding?

Comment: @peter that's a reasonable question. I was reviewing some old code of mine that wasn't conforming to the behaviour I expected. It turns out my expectation was erroneous from misreading the specification of wayland protocols regarding fractional scaling (https://wayland.app/protocols/fractional-scale-v1).   Ultimately, it turns out I don't require the behaviour requested in my post, so while I truly appreciate and am thankful for the input from everybody here, it's somewhat academic for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

As `round()` works per OP's goals, except for some half-way cases, consider:

```
x - floor(x) == 0.5 ? trunc(x) : round(x)
```

or

```
double ipart;
fabs(modf(x, &ipart)) == 0.5 ? ipart : round(x)
```

The above code's results are *independent* of the current rounding mode.

---

Remaining concern: Desired result when `isnan(x)` is true.

Comment: NaN gives NaN. What's the concern?

Comment: @MarkAdler There are many NaNs.  Do we want the same `x`?  Did code give the expected result for various NANs including signaling and non-signaling ones per the C spec? Perhaps it is not important.  IAC, the post does not specify the desired result in this corner case.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, the operation you want is not any of the five operations specified in IEEE 754. Those are (from Wikipedia):

[image: ties to even, ties away from zero, truncation, ceiling, floor]

The five operations are provided respectively by `rint()`, `round()`, `trunc()`, `ceil()`, and `floor()`. (Supposedly the behavior of `rint()` can be changed to be any of those, but I've never seen that implemented.)

While "Round toward 0" (`trunc()`) may sound initially like what you want, it is actually just dropping the fractional part, so 1.9 goes to 1, and -1.9 goes to -1.

So you will need to implement the operation yourself, as shown in the comments.

Comment: Good spot that none of the 5 standard rounding mode directly meet OP's goals.